# bash script to locate variable and replace string between quotes a few lines below

Tags: linux, bash, perl, sed, substitution

I have a plain text file "user database" which contains the same 4 lines repeated over and over again. Each 4 line "array" represents one user in the user database as follows:

```
   'AX112233':  
      uid      => '22044',  
      groups   => ['grp01'],  
      password =>  'passwordXYZ',  
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
```

The `AX112233` is always a unique value. I need a script that when given 2 values namely the unique username `AX112233` and the new password `AX112233:passwordABC`, will be able to locate the unique username in the file and replace the password value between quotes 3 lines down.

So after receiving as input `AX112233:passwordABC` will change the array as follows :

```
'AX112233':
      uid      => '22044',  
      groups   => ['grp01'],  
      password =>  'passwordABC',  
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
```

Ideally something written in `bash/sed/awk/` but doesn't have to be. Any help would be very appreciated.

What I have so far is this Perl script working. I am sure this is a easy one for the Perl experts out there which I am not. The problem with the script is that the initial password is not known so the script need to replace whatever is between the single quotes after `password =>`

```
$ cat input.txt 
AX112233':  
      password =>  'passwordXYZ',  
      uid      => '22044',  
      groups   => ['grp01'],  
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';  
$ perl -pe '++$x and next if /AX112233/; $x-- and s/passwordXYZ/passwordABC/ if $x' input.txt 
AX112233':  
      password =>  'passwordABC',  
      uid      => '22044',  
      groups   => ['grp01'],  
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
```

the other issue with the above is that the line password has to be the very next line below `AX11223`. what if the line were 3 lines below such as

```
AX112233':  
      uid      => '22044',  
      groups   => ['grp01'],  
      password =>  'passwordABC',  
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
```

Comment: This should be very straightforward using `awk`.

Comment: apologies, I should have mentioned what I have been doing, thought this would be an easy one for the programmers out there.

Comment: Give a man a fish, he eats for a day; teach him to fish and he eats for a lifetime. I'm trying to teach you to fish, which means you have to try it yourself.

Comment: Also, showing the code you have so far narrows down the parts we need to explain considerably. Very frequently, the diagnostics in a question turn out to require an answer which explains basic quoting or operator precedence, and not at all what the OP was thinking was the problem.

Comment: If every non-blank line which doesn't contain `=>` is the beginning of a new section, that would seem like a good thing to base your parser on.  Generally, formats which require ad-hoc parsers should be phased out, though; if you have control over the entire system, consider switching it to use a standard data representation like Yaml or JSON instead.

Comment: It matters what your *whole* input file looks like.  Showing only one section does not in any way determine the pattern of the whole file.  In addition, for the one section you did show, you showed it with two different formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple adaptation of your Perl script can easily be made to work:

```
perl -pe '++$x and next if /AX112233/;
          /password\s*=>/ and $x-- and '"s/'[^']*'/'passwordABC'/"' if $x' input.txt
```

There's some shell chicanery in there more than there's really any Perl wizardry.  The first line is identical to what you had.  The second line looks for a line containing `password =>` and then uses some shell trickery to change from single quotes to double quotes (`'"`, and then contains a `s///` command that looks for a single quote, an arbitrary sequence of characters that are not single quotes and another single quote, and replaces that with the new value of the password enclosed in single quotes.  The `"'` reverts back to a single quoted string so that the `if $x` doesn't need a backslash.  There are neater ways to do it, but that is a simple variation on what you had.

Given an input file like this:

```
'AX112233':
      password =>  'passwordXYZ',
      uid      => '22044',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX221133':
      password =>  'passwordXYZ',
      uid      => '22044',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX112233':
      uid      => '22044',
      password =>  'passwordXYZ',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX113322':
      uid      => '22044',
      password =>  'passwordXYZ',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX112233':
      uid      => '22044',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      password =>  'passwordXYZ',
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX112233':
      uid      => '22044',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse',
      password =>  'passwordXYZ';
```

(which has 2 entries for a different user ID, and has the password as the first, second, third or fourth line after the matching user ID) generates:

```
'AX112233':
      password =>  'passwordABC',
      uid      => '22044',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX221133':
      password =>  'passwordXYZ',
      uid      => '22044',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX112233':
      uid      => '22044',
      password =>  'passwordABC',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX113322':
      uid      => '22044',
      password =>  'passwordXYZ',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX112233':
      uid      => '22044',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      password =>  'passwordABC',
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse';
'AX112233':
      uid      => '22044',
      groups   => ['grp01'],
      comment  => 'Mickey Mouse',
      password =>  'passwordABC';
```

Another way to do it:

```
user="AX112233"
password="passwordABC"

perl -pe 'if ('"/$user/"') { ++$x; next }
          if ($x && '"s/password\s*=>\s*'[^']*'/password => '$password'/"') { $x-- }' input.txt
```

This combines the match and substitute in one operation rather than two, and uses regular leading `if` rather than trailing `if` conditionals.  It also allows the user name and new password to be specified via shell variables.

Answer (score 0):

With sed, you can search `$username` using a sed address and replace next password found from that address with the `$newpass` value :

```
username="AX112233"; 
newpass="passwordABC";
sed "/ *'$username'/,/;/{s/^\([ \t]*password => *'\).*/\1$newpass',/}" file
```